# rmarkdown::render_site does not traverse sub directories

Tags: r, bookdown

Why does rmarkdown::render_site() not process subdirectories? I have a .Rmd files in a subfolder and rmd_subdirs: true in _site.yml -- but it does not process any files below the main directory. I have tried rendering with distill and bookdown:html_document2 -- neither works.

Perhaps this doesn't work and I am chasing ghosts?

Comment: I don't see anything in `?rmarkdown::render_site` that would suggest it handles more than one directory.  That's a `bookdown` feature, but it goes in `_bookdown.yml`, not `_site.yml`.